# Using an environment variable in GNU makefile SHELL variable

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

In a makefile, I have the following:

```
SHELL = $(SOME_DIRECTORY)/sh

showme:
    echo $(SHELL)
```

This is on MS Windows.  The situation is that `make` is in the `PATH` (or is being directly invoked) but an acceptable shell (i.e. `sh.exe`) is NOT in the `PATH`.  Neither is it an option to globally modify the `PATH` variable to include a `sh.exe` (too much potential conflict between Cygwin, msysgit, and more).  Therefore, `make` defaults to using the Windows `cmd.exe` command processor, which is hardly ideal.

It *is* an option to set a system-wide environment variable other than `PATH` however.  So I had the bright idea of putting a path to the directory containing sh.exe in `SOME_DIRECTORY` and then using it in the `SHELL` variable in the makefile.  But it's not working for some frustrating reason:

```
make
echo sh.exe
sh.exe
```

If I use any other variable than `SHELL` and echo it, then it prints the expected result.  But of course that doesn't have the desired effect of changing the shell.

What am I missing here?  What do I need to do to have an environment variable with a custom user-specified name (i.e. not `SHELL`, `PATH`, etc.) affect the shell used by make?

Comment: Unfortunately make's behavior with shells on Windows is complicated, because Windows doesn't have a decent shell.  There is some discussion of the Windows-specific behaviors in the GNU make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html  If that doesn't answer your question I recommend you ask on the make-w32@gnu.org mailing list, which is specifically for questions about GNU make on Windows--lots of people who are very knowledgeable about this hang out there.

Comment: Use Cygwin make. _Very_ compatible and cross-platform. (Your example works fine there for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Which make are you using?  GNU make (`gmake`) 3.82 is most common and it should work in the way you expect.  As MadScientist notes, `gmake` behaves differently under windows wrt `SHELL`.

You should be able to set `SHELL` to the full path of an existing executable file, and `gmake` will use it to execute commands.

However: if `SHELL` is not set OR if it is set to a non-existent file, `gmake` will use the value of `ComSpec` (mind the caps) as the shell.

Is there an exe at the test path you're using?  So `$(SOME_DIRECTORY)/sh` is an existing exe?  (Note that you can omit the '.exe' and `gmake` will supply it for you, but the file must exist)